# General introduction to orbifolds?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-group-theory, orbifolds

Where should I go to learn about [orbifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold)?

I am interested in a general introduction that gives precise definitions and clear explanations. I have a fair background in topological and smooth manifold theory.

Thurston's "The Geometry and Topology of Three-Manifolds" I looked at but don't like it too much because here and there it is a bit vague.

Any hints besides the Wikipedia page?

Answer (score 2):

When I was about to post this question on MathOverflow, I found out that it was already [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1861/looking-for-an-introduction-to-orbifolds) there, and the answers are really helpful.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777909/reference-riemannian-orbifolds?rq=1